# MonoDevelop and MonoTouch: what is the runtime version selection about?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have just upgraded to the MonoDevelop 2.8 Alpha and built my MonoTouch app with it. 
I noticed that in the build type dropdown, where I can select Simulator debug/release and iPhone debug/release, there are three separate entries:

- Default Runtime
- Mono 2.10.2
- Mono 2.10.1

My MonoTouch version is 4.0.4.1. I thought MonoTouch was coming with its own Mono runtime. Does the dropdown make any difference for MT projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the target runtime doesn't affect MonoTouch. It only matters for "normal" desktop/server .NET projects.